# toggle with closest at sametime with jQuery for show/hide a item list?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How I can use a `toggle` with `closest` at same time with jQuery for `show/hide` a item list?

I have been trying with this, but it is tiring to have to do it for each element

```
<div class="sidebar-suboptions-box3 main-head-trigger">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sidebar-suboptions-content dsp-f bullet-point active">
                            <div>
                                <div class="sidebar-holder-portf">Portafolio 100000-1</div>
                            <div class="sidebar-suboptions-money">$ 1,022,158.81</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block-profile-portfolios-secondary main-body-trigger" style="display: none;">
                        <hr class="sidebar-inteligo-hr-2">
                        <div>
                            <div class="head-portfolio-active cash-head-trigger">
                                <div class="sidebar-suboptions-title horizontal-bar"> <em>Cash</em> y equivalentes
                                    <br><div class="sidebar-suboptions-money">$ 726,134.93</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="portfolio-active-subitems cash-body-trigger" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="portfolio-active-subitems-head">
                                    <div class="sidebar-subblock-secondary-2">
                                        <div class="sidebar-subblock-title">Cuenta trading
                                            <br><div class="sidebar-subblock-money-2">$ 726,134.93</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="sidebar-subblock-secondary-2">
                                        <div class="sidebar-subblock-title">Prod. estructurados
                                            <br><div class="sidebar-subblock-money-2">$ 726,134.93</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="sidebar-subblock-secondary-2">
                                        <div class="sidebar-subblock-title">Depósitos
                                            <br>
                                            <div class="sidebar-subblock-money-2">$ 726,134.93</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="head-portfolio-active activos-head-trigger">
                                <div class="sidebar-suboptions-title horizontal-bar">Activos
                                    <br><div class="sidebar-suboptions-money-2">$ 726,134.93</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="portfolio-active-subitems activos-body-trigger" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="portfolio-active-subitems-head">
                                    <div class="sidebar-subblock-secondary-2">
                                        <div class="sidebar-subblock-title">Cuenta trading
                                            <br><div class="sidebar-subblock-money-2">$ 726,134.93</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="sidebar-subblock-secondary-2">
                                        <div class="sidebar-subblock-title">Prod. estructurados
                                            <br><div class="sidebar-subblock-money-2">$ 726,134.93</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="sidebar-subblock-secondary-2">
                                        <div class="sidebar-subblock-title">Depósitos
                                            <br>
                                            <div class="sidebar-subblock-money-2">$ 726,134.93</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

```
  $( ".main-head-trigger" ).click(function() {
    $( ".main-body-trigger" ).toggle( "fast", function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });
```

Comment: What element are you specifically trying to toggle? Because you are showing that you are closing the whole element. Having looked at your code there is only one instance of main-body-trigger?

Comment: Every element -trigger. but I´ve many other as main-head-trigger main-body-trigger. so, the list is a little big. for that reason I would like to implement a toggle with closest, is it possible?

Comment: Are you wanting it to close itself on click? If so try:

$( this ).toggle( "fast", function() {
      // Animation complete.
});